# Three.js OBJ and MTL Loaders are not called in loop

Tags: javascript, loops, three.js

I am using the THREE.js OBJ and MTL Loader in an Loop to display different Elements of an 3d animated cake. I need those different Elements because I want the user to be able to change the color of those specific elements (eg. the decor) of the cake.

But whenever I hit a THREE.load function the execution of the iteration of the loop is stopped an it starts with the next (i++). I am new to Javascript. So I am not sure if I am missing an general understanding of loops.

Only in the last gothrough the load function is called and correctly executed. If I use the exact same code without a loop, but rather provide the material-/objectPath hard coded and use several loader everything runs fine.

```
function draw(currentlySelectedCake){

layerArray = [];
// Load  Cake

var i;

for (i = 0; i < currentCakeElements.length; i++){

 if(currentCakeElements[i].endsWith(".mtl")){

    var materialPath = "uploads/" +currentlySelectedCake + "/" + currentCakeElements[i];
    var objectPath = "uploads/" +currentlySelectedCake + "/" + currentCakeElements[i+1];

    var cakeLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();

    cakeLoader.load(materialPath, function (materials) {    
      materials.preload();

      // Load the Cake
      var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
      objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
      objLoader.load(objectPath , function (object) {
        
      
        layer1 = object.clone();
        layer2 = object.clone(); 
        layer3 = object.clone();

        layer1.name = "Layer1Part" + i;
        layer2.name = "Layer2Part" + i;
        layer3.name = "Layer3Part" + i;



        layer1.traverse((child) => {
            if (child.isMesh) {
              child.material = child.material.clone();
            }
          });

          layer2.traverse((child) => {
            if (child.isMesh) {
              child.material = child.material.clone();
            }
          });

          layer3.traverse((child) => {
            if (child.isMesh) {
              child.material = child.material.clone();
            }
          });

        layer2.position.y = tortenhoehe;
        layer3.position.y = tortenhoehe*2*0.75;

     
        camera.lookAt(layer2.position);
        
        layer1Group.add(layer1);
        layer1Group.name = "Layer1";
        layer2Group.add(layer2);
        layer2Group.name = "Layer2";
        layer3Group.add(layer3);
        layer3Group.name = "Layer3";



    });

    layer1Elements.push(layer1Group);
    layer2Elements.push(layer2Group);
    layer3Elements.push(layer3Group); 
});


  }

  
  
});

}



}
```

Comment: It's totally normal what you experience since `load()` is an asynchronous method. I suggest you put breakpoints or `console.log();` statements inside your `onLoad()` callbacks to verify if they are correctly called.

Answer (score 0):

I think this here was my solution. Still in the final process of testing. But looking good so far.

https://www.albertgao.xyz/2016/08/25/why-not-making-functions-within-a-loop-in-javascript/

1. the variable `i` and `j` gets declared first
2. When the first loop runs, an anonymous function has been created inside the loop
3. Inside the newly created anonymous function, it referred a variable `i` which is not in its scope
4. After the first loop, the value of variable `i` accumulates to 3 since the loop runs for 3 times.
5. In the second loop, each function created in the first loop will be invoked.
6. When it gets invoked, the interpreter will check the value of `i`, and it found there is no `i` inside.
7. Since this anonymous has become a closure, the interpreter will look at its scope chain.
8. Finally, the interpreter founds the variable `i`, in the global scope, still within its lexical scope, which is totally legitimate for this anonymous function to refer.
9. And the value of `i` is `3`. We solved it in step 4.
10. So, a `3` will be output.
11. What happens afterwards for the second and third loop is totally the same from step 6~10.